# SearchView.OnQueryTextListener how to display custom suggestions in android

Tags: android

I have implemented all the action bar elements in a Base Activity and i have reused it in other activities. 
This is my search implementation.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
protected AlertDialog mAlertDialog;
protected MenuItem cartMenuItem;
protected MenuItem mSearch;
protected ProgressDialog progress;

private SearchView mSearchView;
private TextView mStatusView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    if (AccountManager.getAccountManager().getCustomer() == null) {
        new getUserInfo().execute();
    }

    mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);

}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    mSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.id_action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearch.getActionView();
    setupSearchView(mSearch);
    return true;
}

// search functions

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

    if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(
                MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (searchManager != null) {
        List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

        SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
        for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
            if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("application")) {
                info = inf;
            }
        }
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
    }
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    Log.i("search", "Inside onQueryTextChange ");

    if(newText.trim().equals(""))
        Log.i("search","string is empty");
    else
    {
        //mStatusView.setText("Query = " + newText);
        Log.i("search","newText : "+newText);
    }
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searched Word : "+newText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Log.i("search", "Inside onQueryTextSubmit");
//  mStatusView.setText("Query = " + query + " : submitted");
    //Handle Search 

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Searched Word is "+query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return false;
}

public boolean onClose() {
    mStatusView.setText("Closed!");
    return false;
}

protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
    return false;
}
```

This is the home.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.fingertipcart.HomeActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/id_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

How do i get custom dropdown suggestions to search queries?

Comment: use `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter`

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you please post some code or a tutorial?

Comment: ask uncle Googke for `setSuggestionsAdapter`, you should get some stuff